# C# Linq to VB.NET (not a From In Where ... query style)

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

How would I convert this kind of expression in VB.NET? I'm stomped!

`bool exists=repo.Exists<Post>(x=>x.Title=="My Title");`

This is from the SubSonic docs here: http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim exists = repo.Exists(Of Post)(Function(x) x.Title = "My Title")
```